# Linux Awk help on code

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need to print the contents of a file, and give a title to each column, leaving enough space to be readable, and then I need to output this into a new file. I followed this tutorial for a good while but I've gotten stuck.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-introduction-tutorial-7-awk-print-examples

This is the example code they use, which would give me exactly what I need to do with mine. But it will not work when I adjust it.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "Name\tDesignation\tDepartment\tSalary";}
{print $2,"\t",$3,"\t",$4,"\t",$NF;}
END{print "Report Generated\n--------------";
}' employee.txt
```

This is mine, as unlike the example, I want the whole document printed and don't really want this "report generated" nonsense under it. I tried adding {print;}' to the end after end, and made sure to start a new line and... nothing.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {Print "Firstname\tLastname\tPoints";} END > awktest.txt > done
```

Where have I gone wrong? It keeps giving me the response Source line 2.

Comment: You are missing a quote; you don't need an `END` address if you don't want to do anything at the end of file; `> awktest.txt > done` part does not make much sense.

Comment: There's no closing `'`. I assume your shell is waiting for you to enter the rest of the string you started after `awk`, then `'`.

Comment: Whoever wrote that awk tutorial needs to take an awk tutorial. Ignore it, it's full of nonsense and will start you off on the wrong foot. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the footline, just drop out anything starting from END till the closing ':

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Name\tDesignation\tDepartment\tSalary";} {print $2,"\t",$3,"\t",$4,"\t",$NF;}' employee.txt
```

In your second example, you left out the closing ', and I suspect you put one more ">" than needed:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Firstname\tLastname\tPoints";}' awktest.txt > done
```

The latter example will however silently ignore everything read from "awktest.txt".

Comment: This will just print the header, and none of the data.

Comment: @e0k Which one? The first example, or the second one that already says it will ignore the input file?

Comment: Yes, the second one (the one with no per-record clause and only a `BEGIN` clause) would list no data, but yes it does state that. You might want to use `OFS="\t"` in the `BEGIN` clause instead of having to list all those `"\t"` in the `print` statements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have missed out the actual printing of the columns and a source file, also I read that you don't need any END actions...

```
awk 'BEGIN {Print "Firstname\tLastname\tPoints";} END > awktest.txt > done`
```

Should be...

```
awk 'BEGIN {Print "Firstname\tLastname\tPoints";}{print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",$3;}' source_file.txt > awktest.txt`
```

Just remember to change the $1,$2,$3 to what columns on the source file you need.

FYI. I'm no expert, just reading the tuts :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need is just to insert a header line, which can easily be done with `sed` (as well as `awk`) or with `cat`

```
$ sed '1iFirstname\tLastname\tPoints' file > output.file
```

or

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "Firstname\tLastname\tPoints"} 1' file > output.file
```

or

```
$ cat <(echo -e "Firstname\tLastname\tPoints") file > output.file
```

Answer (score 0):

The awk print function is named `print`, not `Print`. idk why all the solutions are including `,"\t",` in their print statements. You don't want that - you want to set `-v OFS='\t'` at the start of the script and then just use `,` between fields. All you want is:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
BEGIN {print "Name", "Designation", "Department", "Salary"}
{print $2, $3, $4, $NF}
}' employee.txt
```

assuming those are the correct field numbers you want to print from your data. Sample input/output in your question would be extremely useful to help us answer it.